# Qt 5.4, dynamic OpenGL and get_program_binary extension

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

We're trying to port our program to Qt 5.4 -opengl dynamic implementation.
Before Qt 5.4, we used separate Desktop OpenGL/DX9-ANGLE builds and ifdefs like this:

```
#ifdef USE_GLES
    binf = new QOpenGLExtension_OES_get_program_binary();
    binf->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
#else
    bingl = new QOpenGLExtension_ARB_get_program_binary();
    bingl->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
#endif
```

USE_GLES is defined in my .pro (qmake) file, based on opengl implementation set on build Qt.

For -opengl dynamic, **QOpenGLExtension_OES_get_program_binary** extension is not available even if Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES is used, because it hides under #ifdef in QOpenGLExtensions.h

What should we do? Re-implement all ARB/OES extensions in our code (i.e. declare entry points and do function resolve on runtime, depending of available extensions list)? Is this problem already resolved by the Qt team?

Comment: Managed to resolved all extensions manually, by context()->getProcAddress()

Comment: If you've solved it, you can answer your own question and then accept it after two days.

Comment: This is not solved: many QOpenGLExtensions (with OES/ARB counterparts) seems unusable in QT5.4+ Dynamic OpenGL mode.

So, if there is some Qt-specific 'right' way, I'll happy to see the answer

Comment: Oh, ok. Is there a bug report for this?